# Insert item and change the array's dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to add dimensions to an array, but expand_dims always adds dimension of size 1.

**Input:**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

**What expand_dims does:**

```
[[[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]], [[7], [8], [9]]]
```

**What I want:**

```
[[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]], [[1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6]], [[1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9]]]
```

Basically I want to replace each scalar in the matrix by a vector `[1, x]` where x is the original scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using broadcasting and [`np.insert()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) function:

```
In [32]: a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]) 
In [33]: np.insert(a[:,:,None], 0, 1, 2)                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[33]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 3]],

       [[1, 4],
        [1, 5],
        [1, 6]],

       [[1, 7],
        [1, 8],
        [1, 9]]])
```

Comment: I figured this out using `expand_dims` which should be equivalent to `a[:,:,None]` but didn't need the extra dimension after all. I had it all confused: `np.insert(a, 0, 1, axis=1)` is all I needed. This is still the correct answer to my question though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways of constructing the new array.

You could initial the array with right shape and fill, and copy values:

```
In [402]: arr = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
In [403]: arr
Out[403]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
In [404]: res = np.ones((3,3,2),int)
In [405]: res[:,:,1] = arr
In [406]: res
Out[406]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 3]],

       [[1, 4],
        [1, 5],
        [1, 6]],

       [[1, 7],
        [1, 8],
        [1, 9]]])
```

You could join the array with a like size array of 1s.  `concatenate` is the basic joining function:

```
In [407]: np.concatenate((np.ones((3,3,1),int), arr[:,:,None]), axis=2)
Out[407]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 3]],

       [[1, 4],
        [1, 5],
        [1, 6]],

       [[1, 7],
        [1, 8],
        [1, 9]]])
```

`np.stack((np.ones((3,3),int), arr), axis=2)` does the same thing under the covers.  `np.dstack` ('d' for depth) does it as well.  The `insert` in the other answer also does this.